# PHP : In multidimensional array how to merge child array with same key-value?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have array multidimensional array,

```
Array(

    Array
    (
        [UTTL_M_FT] => 2616.00
        [TUG] => 5310
        [univercity] => 1
        [year] => 2010
    )

    Array
    (
        [UTTL_M_FT] => 2710.00
        [TUG] => 5405
        [univercity] => 1
        [year] => 2012
    )

    Array
    (
        [UTTL_M_FT] => 2622.00
        [TUG] => 7803
        [univercity] => 2
        [year] => 2010
    )

    Array
    (
        [UTTL_M_FT] => 2759.00
        [TUG] => 8423
        [univercity] => 2
        [year] => 2012
    )

    Array
    (
        [UTTL_M_FT] => 3330.00
        [TUG] => 6879
        [univercity] => 3
        [year] => 2011
    )

    Array
    (
        [UTTL_M_FT] => 3373.00
        [TUG] => 6796
        [univercity] => 3
        [year] => 2013
    )

    Array
    (
        [UFTF_ASN] => 749
        [UFTF_TTL] => 5296
        [univercity] => 1
        [year] => 2013
    )

)
```

And we require array in following format,

```
Array(

[univercity] => 1,

Array
    (
        [UTTL_M_FT] => 2616.00
        [TUG] => 5310       
        [year] => 2010
    ),

Array
    (
        [UTTL_M_FT] => 2710.00
        [TUG] => 5405
        [year] => 2012
    ),  

Array
    (
        [UFTF_ASN] => 749
        [UFTF_TTL] => 5296
        [year] => 2013
    )

),


Array(
[univercity] => 2,

Array
    (
        [UTTL_M_FT] => 2759.00
        [TUG] => 8423       
        [year] => 2012
    )

),  

Array(

[univercity] => 3,

    Array
    (
        [UTTL_M_FT] => 3330.00
        [TUG] => 6879       
        [year] => 2011
    ),
    Array
    (
        [UTTL_M_FT] => 3373.00
        [TUG] => 6796
        [year] => 2013
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you, append the same university id array into the main container data array

```
<?php   

     $data =array();
        foreach($inpuArray as $array){
            $universityId = $array['univercity'];
            unset($array['univercity']);
            $data['univercity'][$universityId][] = $array;
        }
        print_r($data);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$new = array();
$i=0;
foreach($array as $a){
    $u = $a['univercity'];
    unset($a['univercity']);
    $found = false;
    foreach($new as $k=>$v){
        if(isset($new[$k]['univercity']) && $new[$k]['univercity'] == $u){
            $new[$k][] = $a;
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$found){
        $new[$i]['univercity']=$u;
        $new[$i][]=$a;
        $i++;
    }
}
echo"<pre>";
var_export($new);
echo"</pre>";
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'univercity' => 1,
    0 => 
    array (
      'UTTL_M_FT' => 2616,
      'TUG' => 5310,
      'year' => 2010,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'UTTL_M_FT' => 2710,
      'TUG' => 5405,
      'year' => 2012,
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'UFTF_ASN' => 749,
      'UFTF_TTL' => 5296,
      'year' => 2013,
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'univercity' => 2,
    0 => 
    array (
      'UTTL_M_FT' => 2622,
      'TUG' => 7803,
      'year' => 2010,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'UTTL_M_FT' => 2759,
      'TUG' => 8423,
      'year' => 2012,
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'univercity' => 3,
    0 => 
    array (
      'UTTL_M_FT' => 3330,
      'TUG' => 6879,
      'year' => 2011,
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'UTTL_M_FT' => 3373,
      'TUG' => 6796,
      'year' => 2013,
    ),
  ),
)
```